# How can i select from more than one table in a SqlDataSource asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select, sqldatasource

i have a web page, that will load data from three tables
is there a way to load all the data at once using a Sqldatasource, or must i do it in coding?

i also want to sort it. but that i know how to do. and all the data goes into a gridview, which is why i want to use just one Sqldatasource.

this is what i have so far:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ 
ConnectionStrings:testpicsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tball]
select * from tb1
select * from tb2"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and do i just add

```
sort id desc
```

to them all?

i just want to know can it be done with one Sqldatasource?

btw, I'm using c# and sql (obviously)

sorry forgot to add the schema from the tables

all the tables are the same: they have id, desc and pic

```
id int primary key identity not null,
[desc] varchar(max) null,
pic varbinary(max) null
```

that is used for all tables. 
so if i had to join, on where or what would i join?

Comment: Did you try with UNION in one Sqldatasource ? see my answer below. You could of course still use WHERE-clause when using unions. E.g. select... where id = xx...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) to select the columns from the different tables...

```
select * from tb1
union all 
select * from tb2
union all
select * from tb3
order by id desc;
```

---

`union all` - will show all records in your result.
`union` - will remove duplicate records from your result.

`Union all` will give better performance as the database engine won't have any overhead for managing the result to remove the duplicates.

Comment: 1+ , The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a view in your database that will collect all the data you need and then query it in your c# application.

Answer (score 0):

[Go here: Union](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

select * from Table1
union all
select * from Table2
order by 1